# Are these sentences the same? "To sit at someone's feet" vs. "To sit at the feet of someone"

Tags: meaning

Examples:

> 1. He sat at the feet of his professor.
> 2. He sat at his professor's feet.

I found the expression "sit at sb's feet" in [Oxford dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sit) and I found the expression "sit at the feet of sb" in [The free dictionary by Farlex](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sit+at+the+feet+of). I've read both and it seems they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a literal statement, I would say both are equally common, and equally valid. In some "metaphoric" usages, such as...

> 1: [He learned at the feet of the master](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22learned%20at%20the%20feet%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22learned%20at%20the%20feet%20of%20the%20master%22&oq=%22learned%20at%20the%20feet%20of%20the%20master%22&gs_l=serp.3...102063.104106.0.104816.11.11.0.0.0.2.208.975.7j3j1.11.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.k1oFvMjuop8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=844)
>    2: [He learned at the master's feet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22learned%20at%20the%20feet%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22learned%20at%20the%20master%27s%20feet%22&oq=%22learned%20at%20the%20master%27s%20feet%22&gs_l=serp.3...2899.9822.0.10262.23.18.0.0.0.6.401.1861.13j3j1j0j1.18.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.cVw8ddTW9u0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=844)

...the first version is far more common. Probably because the more verbose form adds a touch of "gravitas" (makes it sound more formal). But in more "homely" contexts, such as...

> 3: [He learned at his mother's knee](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22learned%20at%20the%20feet%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22learned%20at%20his%20mother%27s%20knee%22&oq=%22learned%20at%20his%20mother%27s%20knee%22&gs_l=serp.3...179252.186984.1.187256.34.28.0.0.0.5.144.2177.24j4.28.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.HFqZtOz2sFk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=844)
>    4: [He learned at the knees of his mother](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22learned%20at%20the%20feet%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22learned%20at%20the%20knee%20of%20his%20mother%22&oq=%22learned%20at%20the%20knee%20of%20his%20mother%22&gs_l=serp.3...81543.81543.4.82108.1.1.0.0.0.0.61.61.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.gfxFjeOpFrI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=844) (or [knees](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22learned%20at%20the%20feet%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22learned%20at%20the%20knees%20of%20his%20mother%22&oq=%22learned%20at%20the%20knees%20of%20his%20mother%22&gs_l=serp.3...24083.24083.5.24473.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.AkiEbUXIL0w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=844))

...those second forms are virtually unknown. So I would say only use the possessive apostrophe in these constructions when it's an informal/personal context.

Comment: Oh, good tip. I didn't know that using the possessive apostrophe was an informal usage. Could you tell me if saying these expression with "knees" is the same as "feet"?

Comment: @DragonBuster It's a different image: a child will lean on its mother's knee, but a student will ordinarily sit at a decorous distance from a master.

Comment: I wouldn't say possessive apostrophe is always (or even markedly) informal, but I think the usage figures in those 4/5 links do indicate that it's a consideration. Mostly, it's just that we *usually* use the apostrophe with actual parts of *people* - so #1 is "atypical", which is what makes it a bit "special/respectful/reverent".